# Finding coefficient $c_n$ of Cauchy product for $a_k = (\frac{-1}{2})^k, b_k = \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I need to find the coefficient $c_n=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k b_{n-k}$ for the Cauchy product $\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k=(\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k)(\sum_{k=0}^n b_k)$ with $(a_k)=(\frac{-1}{2})^k$ and $(b_k) = \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}$

I have $\sum_{k=0}^n c_k = \sum_{k=0}^n (\frac{-1}{2})^k \frac{(-1)^{n-k}}{n-k+1}$

What is a closed form solution for 
$$\sum_{k=0}^n(\frac{-1}{2})^k(-1)^{n-k}\frac{1}{n-k+1}$$

I tried to simplify this, but got stuck:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n(\frac{-1}{2})^k(-1)^{n-k}\frac{1}{n-k+1}= \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{2^k}(-1)^{n-k}\frac{1}{n-k+1}$$

$$= (-1)^n\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{2^k}\frac{1}{n-k+1}$$

Edit: Also for the solution the following recurrence has to hold: $$|c_{k+1}|=\frac{1}{2}|c_k|+\frac{1}{k+2}$$

Can anybody please help me with this?

Comment: Is there any reason to believe there is a nice closed form?

Comment: The question asks for a solution for $c_k$ so I think there very likely is a closed form. Also in case it might help, the next question asks one to show that $|c_{k+1}|=\frac{1}{2}|c_k|+\frac{1}{k+2}$

Comment: The recurrence is direct from the sum you have. I think the sum is all that is expected, because I tend to believe there is no nice closed form. You can start explicitly computing the first ten or twenty $c_k$ and look for a pattern, but don't be too optimistic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have one question though. If there is no closed form solution, how can I evaluate the limit of the Cauchy product? I mean I would have an infinite series that sum over a finite series, how can I evaluate the value of that infinite series then?

Comment: $\sum a_n$ is absolutely convergent. Therefore $\sum c_n = (\sum a_n)(\sum b_n)$.

Comment: Use generating functions: 

Let $f(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}a_n x^n = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\left(-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^nx^n = \dfrac{1}{1+\tfrac{x}{2}}$,

and let $g(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}b_n x^n = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n+1}x^n = \ln(1+x)$. 

Then, $\dfrac{\ln(1+x)}{1+\tfrac{x}{2}} = f(x)g(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k = 0}^{n}a_kb_{n-k}\right)x^n = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}c_nx^n$. 

So, now we just need the taylor series coefficients of $f(x)g(x) = \dfrac{\ln(1+x)}{1+\tfrac{x}{2}}$.